# Peter randomly selected two diagonals of a regular hexagon. What is the probability that....

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Peter randomly selected two diagonals of a regular hexagon. What is the probability that....

a) the diagonals he selected intersect with each other?

b) the diagonals he selected have the same length?

PLEASE HELP! I have no clue how to solve this at all.

Comment: It would help if you said a bit about what you *do* know how to solve.

Comment: How many diagonals does a regular hexagon have?

What can be the length of such a diagonal?

What's the distribution of the lengths of the diagonals? (How many are there with a length of $x$ for all lengths $x$.)

Answering these should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

For a, you might as well fix one end of the first diagonal.  There are two kinds of diagonals from that point, straight across and the other.  There are not many other diagonals.  Do you count the other ones coming from this point as intersecting?  Just count.  For b, start by computing how many diagonals there are in a regular hexagon and group them by length.